# more boundary locations for a more precise shape

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get a polygon shape for a state.

The geocoding api just returns just 2 locations for boundaries, northeast and southwest lat/longs, which are clearly insufficient to get a precise shape.

Eg., for North Carolina, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=NC,
below is part of the json response

```
    "geometry" : {
    "bounds" : {
       "northeast" : {
          "lat" : 36.5881568,
          "lng" : -75.4599515
       },
       "southwest" : {
          "lat" : 33.840969,
          "lng" : -84.32186899999999
       }
```

While i can still form a shape out of this, it will be just a rectangle always. 
What i am looking for is an api that returns more boundary lat/longs to improve the precision of the shape.

Could you please let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geocoder only returns the bounding box of the polygon (so you can fit the map to show it) not the bounds of the state.  To get the bounds of a state you need to have a source for that data.  On reasonable free source is the FusionTable containing the NaturalEarth data set:

http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2011/02/natural-earth-vectors-in-cloud.html

Those polygons overlaid on a Google Maps Javascript API v3 map:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=United%20States%20of%20America

The FusionTable containing these polygons is:
Encrypted ID: 19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA
(deprecated numeric id: 420419)

[link](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the public data available in fusion tables is the way to go, even though it says its an experimental effort.